# select2 v4.0.3: prevent that the ajax call is send when adding a value in searchbox

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Is het possible to prevent that an ajax call is made when adding a search value in the searchbox of the select2 v4.0.3 dropdown?

We want to only perform an ajax call when we open the select2 dropdown and use the search function of the searchbox without doing another ajax call with the entered value.

---added code example---

js code:

```
    $("#gebruikerId").select2({
    width: "200px",
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
    ajax: {
        url: "webservice.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 0,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
              request: "getUsers",
              q: params.term // search term
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
                var results = [];
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    results.push({
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.omschrijving
                    });
                });
                return {
                    results: results
                };
        },
        cache: true     
      }
});
```

php code:

```
<div class="gb-select-div">
    <select id="gebruikerId" name="gebruikerId" class="input-select-class"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put some code of selectbox and js, here? what do you have it right now.

Comment: I have updated the post by adding the requested code to the post.